# Update dataclass fields from a dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

How can I update the fields of a dataclass using a dict?

**Example**:

```
@dataclass
class Sample:
    field1: str
    field2: str
    field3: str
    field4: str

sample = Sample('field1_value1', 'field2_value1', 'field3_value1', 'field4_value1')
updated_values = {'field1': 'field1_value2', 'field3': 'field3_value2'}
```

I want to do something like

```
sample.update(updated_values)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to make a small class and inherit from it:

```py
class Updateable(object):
    def update(self, new):
        for key, value in new.items():
            if hasattr(self, key):
                setattr(self, key, value)

@dataclass
class Sample(Updateable):
    field1: str
    field2: str
    field3: str
    field4: str
```

You can read [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/setattr) if you want to learn more about getattr and setattr

Answer (score 9):

Updating the underlying `__dict__` seems to work if you have a basic dataclass:

```py
sample.__dict__.update({ 'field1': 'value1' })
```